# Aligning Radio button/multiple Search boxes horizontally same line

Tags: html, css

So far everything is lined up except the last search box. I'm kinda new and it's taking me way to long to figure this out. I need to align all of my search boxes, drop downs, and radio buttons on the same line and centered. The search buttons and radio buttons keep moving to the line below. I added float left to the form and it brought the radio button up but it seems out of alignment. Ill be adding a calendar option and need it all on the same line. what's the best way to do this?

```css
.table
{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

        <select>
            <option value="Last Name">Last Name</option>
            <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
            <option value="Employee ID">Employee ID</option>
            <option value="Job ID">Job ID</option>
            <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
            <option value="Ipad Number">Ipad Number</option>

        </select>

        <input type="text" name="text" class="Search" placeholder="Search Here" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />

        <select>
            <option value="Phones">Phones</option>
            <option value="Tablets">Tablets</option>
            <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
            <option value="Cellphone">Cellphone</option>
            <option value="Docks">Docks</option>
            <option value="Monitors">Monitors</option>
            <option value="Gloves">Gloves</option>
            <option value="Sleeves">Sleeves</option>

        </select>
    </div>


    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="Before" value="male"> Before<br>
        <input type="radio" name="After" value="female"> After<br>
    </form>


    
    <input type="text" name="text" class="Search" placeholder="Search Here" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will put everything in one line.

```css
.table {
  display: inline-block
}

.Search {
  width: 10%
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

  <select>
    <option value="Last Name">Last Name</option>
    <option value="First Name">First Name</option>
    <option value="Employee ID">Employee ID</option>
    <option value="Job ID">Job ID</option>
    <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
    <option value="Ipad Number">Ipad Number</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="text" class="Search" placeholder="Search Here" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />

  <select>
    <option value="Phones">Phones</option>
    <option value="Tablets">Tablets</option>
    <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
    <option value="Cellphone">Cellphone</option>
    <option value="Docks">Docks</option>
    <option value="Monitors">Monitors</option>
    <option value="Gloves">Gloves</option>
    <option value="Sleeves">Sleeves</option>
  </select>
         
  <input type="radio" name="Before" value="male"> Before
  <input type="radio" name="After" value="female"> After
  <input type="text" name="text" class="Search" placeholder="Search Here" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: @AndrewShults good to know. I have made some edits to my previous answer. I think you should be able to directly use it. If this answered your question, please accept this as answer.

Comment: Ok this is literally my first post on here. I don't see where to accept this as an answer. Do you know where?

Answer (score 0):

Forms are block elements. You can change this via CSS:

```
form { display: inline }
```

or

```
form {display: inline-block }
```